# container does not exist

Tags: html, asp.net, repeater, flags

i use repeater in my project .. so when user add new document then i want to highlight new add documents same as gmail when we see new email in gmail account then email is in bold and then we able to see someone send email same as i want when new record added then how to highlight or identify in other ways? 
so someone suggest me use flag for this and then when i try to use flags first i add column in table like this
[image: pic]

and then when i use like this in repeater

```
 <tr
   style='<%if(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "datatype")== 1) 
    { %> background-color: yellow;  <% }
     else { %> background-color: white;
     <%} %>'>
```

it shows me error

```
Compilation Error 
 Description: An error occurred during the 
compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please 
review the following specific error details and modify your source code 
appropriately.
 Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'Container' does not exist in the current context
Source Error                    
                      Line 124:<%--                            <tr>--%>
Line 125:                            <tr
Line 126:                                  style='<% if (DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "datatype")== 1) { %> background-color: yellow;  <% }
```

anyone please help where is the problem  and how i solve this or is there another way to solve this ?
THANKU

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is doing inline code which doesn't work in ASP.NET Webforms.

You can create css class for your regular and highlighted rows and apply that class accordingly. I would go with creating a separate function that takes the "datatype" as a parameter returns a css Classname based on the value. Call that function then from .aspx to set the tr class attribute.

It is shown in [this article](http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-set-row-background-color-or-apply-Css-to-da).

Comment: i try this article and it cannot show me any error but when i debug and add new record then this can not show me any effect ....

Comment: may be you need to upload your latest code with changes so as to see what wrong in there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<tr style='<%# getBackground(Eval("FieldName")) %>'>
```

where `FieldName` is the name of the field as it comes from the `DataSource`. Then make a public function in the code behind. I am assuming you are using c# since you did not tag any language:

**C#**

```
public string getBackground(Object fieldName)
{
    if ((bool)fieldName)
    {
        return "background-color: yellow;";
    }
    else
    {
        return "background-color: white;";
    }
}
```

This assumes the field is a boolean, but you can cast to any primitive or custom datatype.

Comment: FIELD NAME MEANS COLUMN NAME OR SOMETHING ELSE?

Comment: AND YES I CREATE SEPARATE CLASSLIBRARY AND THEN ADD CLASSLIBRARY.DLL IN REFERENCE IN ASP.NET WEB APPLICATION

Comment: AND WHEN I TRY THIS and make public string getbackground in classlibrary and then add this tr style... in .aspx form it shows me error .....Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'getBackground' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:


Line 122:                            </HeaderTemplate>
Line 123:                            <ItemTemplate>
Line 124:                            <tr style='<%# getBackground(Eval("FieldName")) %>'>

Comment: FieldName would be the column name. The function must not be in the class library, it should be in the same .aspx file.

Comment: column name which i add in column name (yes_no)) in table (pic in question) or something else?